# Unable to populate string with checkbox selection

Tags: java, android, textview, android-checkbox

I have a simple question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm hoping someone can help, but after researching checkboxes, I still cannot solve this.

Here is my code:

```
CheckBox chkbxUpgrade;
TextView txtViewResult;
Double cost;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    chkbxUpgrade = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxUpgrade);

    onCheckboxClicked(cost);
}

public double onCheckboxClicked(Double cost) {
    if (chkbxUpgrade.isChecked()) {
        cost = 6.99;
    }
    else {
        cost = 4.99;
    }
    return cost;
}

public void onClickOrder(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Order Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    txtViewResult.setText("Price: $" + cost);
}
```

Shouldn't my textview be populated with 4.99 if the checkbox is not checked, or 6.99 if it is checked? I cannot figure out why it is not populating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml sould look like :

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/your check box id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

Then change your method to be:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

   if (checked)
   { 
       cost = 6.99;
   }
   else
   {
      cost =4.99;
   }

}
```

Comment: you are most welcome. Don't forget to save the cost variable in case the activity has been closed . look at this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate

Answer (score 1):

To see if a JCheckBox is check-marked you would use **.isSelected()** not **.isChecked()**. There is no **.isChecked()** with a JCheckBox:

```
if (chkbxUpgrade.isSelected()) {
    cost = 6.99;
}
else {
    cost = 4.99;
}
```

unless using the method from a different Class.
Also, since your **cost** variable has been declared as a class field it is not required to pass it as a parameter or return it from a method since the variable is class global. Your **onCheckboxClicked()** method would work just as well with:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked() {
    if (chkbxUpgrade.isSelected()) {
        cost = 6.99;
    }
    else {
        cost = 4.99;
    }
}
```

Unless using the **onCheckboxClicked()** method from another class.

Comment: Thank you, I changed around the code and it now populates a price. The only issue, is whether the checkbox is checked or not, I always get 4.99 as a price. Shouldn't it be 6.99 if the box is checked? Do you happen to know why I am getting that issue?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm always getting 4.99 because I'm calling the checkbox method in my onCreate? So since it starts out as unchecked (4.99), it is not updating when it finally gets checked by the user?

Comment: @burgoyne  look at my answer